# SQL JOIN 2 table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

i have 2 table like this

student

```
|-----------------------|
| id  | name   | value  |
|-----------------------|
| F01 | Ruben  | 4      |
| F02 | Dani   | 2      |
| F03 | Mike   | 3      |
| F04 | John   | 4      |
|-----------------------|
```

tutor

```
|-------------------------|
| id | code  | student_id |
|-------------------------|
| 1  | S2244 | F01        |
| 2  | S3251 | F02        |
| 3  | S2244 | F03        |
| 4  | S2244 | F04        |
|-------------------------|
```

note, tutor.code ( S2244 and S3251) is foreign key from another table, tutor.student_id is foreign key from student table, how to make the two tables combined and produce a result as below?

```
|-----------------------|
| id  | name   | value  |
|-----------------------|
| F01 | Ruben  | 4      |
| F03 | Mike   | 3      |
| F04 | John   | 4      |
|-----------------------|
```

the result is the same as the student table, but the data is released based on what is stored in the tutor table, in the tutor table there is code "S3251" / "F02" which is not displayed in the results table

this is like the "WHERE" condition but the WHERE 'condition ' is used in other tables, I've tried using JOIN but i can't, or maybe my table design is wrong? Please help, this code that I made but didn't get a good result

```
SELECT st.id, st.name, st.value FROM student st JOIN tutor tt ON tt.code = 'S2244'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select s.*
from students s
where exists (
    select 1 from tutor t where t.student_id = s.student_id and t.code = 'S2244'
)
```

This makes more sense than a `join`, since you are not `select`ing from the `tutor` table).

The problem with your original attempt is that you are missing a joining condition on `student_id` (which is common to both tables). The syntax would be:

```
select s.* 
from student s 
inner join tutor t on s.id = t.student_id 
where t.code = 's2244'
```

Comment: I fixed a few typos in your second query

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @GMB's answer above, which is absolutely correct, you could also do the following, which I think might be more intuitive for a beginner developer:

```
select * from student
where id in (
   select student_id from tutor where id = 's2244'
)
```